# Can't access combodate from JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, combodate

I suspect that the problem I'm having is just a misunderstanding of JS scope or something.

I have moment.js and combodate.js linked and the following code works fine when run immediately after my form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#birthday').combodate();
    });
</script>
```

But if I want to run it in a function (to clear the form, for instance):

```
var launchChildRegisterModal = function() {
    //Do other stuff...
    $('#birthday').combodate();
}
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: $(...).combodate is not a function
```

Do I have to do something special to use it from within a function?

EDIT: to clarify, the following code does work:

```
<form id="register-form" action='<?= base_url('user/register/' . issetor($invite_code, '')) ?>' method="POST">
        <!-- Account Type hidden form element-->
        <input type="hidden" name="account_type" class="form-control" id="account_type" value="<?= issetor($_GET['account_type'], '') ?>" />

        <div class="control-group"> 
          <!-- First Name --> 
          <!--<label class="control-label"  for="first_name">First Name</label>-->
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="<?=isset($set_values['first_name'])? $set_values['first_name'] : ''?>" required>
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" id="last_name_group"> 
          <!-- Last Name --> 
          <!--<label class="control-label"  for="last_name">Last Name</label>-->
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?=isset($set_values['last_name'])? $set_values['last_name'] : ''?>">
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" id="username_group" style="display: none;"> 
          <!-- Username --> 
          <!--<label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>-->
          <div class="controls guidingText">
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?=isset($set_values['username'])? $set_values['username'] : ''?>">
            <p>Username can contain any letters or numbers, but must be 20 characters or less.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" id="email_group"> 
          <!-- Email --> 
          <!-- <label class="control-label" for="email">Email </label>-->
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?= issetor($set_values['email'], issetor($parent_email, '')) ?>">
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" id="gender_group" style="display: none;"> 
          <!-- Gender -->
          <!--<label class="control-label"  for="gender">Gender</label>-->
          <div class="controls">
            <select name="gender" id="gender" class="genderSelect" value="<?=isset($set_values['gender'])? $set_values['gender'] : 'Gender'?>">
              <option>Gender</option>
              <option>Male</option>
              <option>Female</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" id="birthday_group" style="display: none;"> 
          <!-- Birthday --> 
          <div class="controls input-append date">
          <p>Birthday</p>
            <input type="text" id="birthday" class="bdateSelect" name="birthday" placeholder="Birthday" data-format="MM/DD/YYYY" data-template="MMM / D / YYYY" value="<?= date('m/d/Y') ?>">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" id="parent_email_group" style="display: none;"> 
          <!-- Parent Email --> 
          <!-- <label class="control-label" for="parent_email">Parent Email</label>-->
          <div class="controls guidingText">
            <input type="text" id="parent_email" name="parent_email" placeholder="Parent Email" value="<?=isset($set_values['parent_email'])? $set_values['parent_email'] : ''?>">
            <p>If not available, leave blank for now.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group"> 
          <!-- Password --> 
          <!-- <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>-->
          <div class="controls guidingText">
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" pattern="^\S{8,}$" required title="Password must be 8 characters or more.">
            <p>Password must be at least 8 characters</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group"> 
          <!-- Password Confirmation --> 
          <!--<label class="control-label"  for="password_confirm">Confirm Password</label>-->
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="password" id="password_confirm" name="password_confirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" minlength="8" pattern="^\S{8,}$" onchange="check(this)"  required>
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
        </div>

          <div class="control-group"> 
          <!-- Password Confirmation --> 
          <!--<label class="control-label"  for="password_confirm">Confirm Password</label>-->
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="zip" id="zip" name="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" minlength="5" pattern="^\d{5,}$" onchange="check(this)">
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group"> 
          <!-- Submit Button -->
            <button class="button3" id="form-submit-btn">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#birthday').combodate();
        });
      </script>
```

but further down the page I have the launchChildRegisterModal() function above which throws the error.

Comment: show how you are referencing it.

Comment: In my <head> I have included script tags for moment.js and combodate.js. Further down the page I have a <form> with an <input type="text" id="birthday">

I can call combodate() on the input if the call is NOT in a function, but further down the page in my launchChildRegisterModal function I get the "not a function" error.

Comment: I should also specify that the launchChildRegisterModal function is called via button click, so it is not done on page load like the rest.

Answer (score 2):

It can be run from within a function.

Are you calling the function after you've already initialised the combodate function on domready? If that's the case, it won't work. If you want to reset the value, you have to use the setValue method.

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/nz9vf9a5/

Combodate is initialised on dom ready and then again on button click it calls a function which sets a new value.

```
$(function () {
  $('#date').combodate();
});

$("button").click(function () {
  launchChildRegisterModal();
});
var launchChildRegisterModal = function () {
  $('#date').combodate('setValue', "12/12/2003");
};
```

The same structure can be used if you only want it initialised on button click using the value supplied in the dom.

```
$(function () {
 // $('#date').combodate();
});

$("button").click(function () {
  launchChildRegisterModal();
});
var launchChildRegisterModal = function () {
  $('#date').combodate();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

1- Check that in your included scripts that you've included combodate.js and also that you've included it after moment.js since combodate is based on moment.js

2 - be sure in your html that you have an input with birthday as id.